# Web filter blocks some Stack Overflow URLs

Tags: support, hyperlinks

Some URLs on Stack Overflow contain the word "tagged." The proxy on my corporate network hates this word. It thinks I'm trying to visit the site "tagged.com." How can I view tag-related pages at work?

**Update:**
I changed jobs, and the proxy in my new environment does not block me. However, I am still concerned about my former co-workers. They are not yet able to take full advantage of the immense knowledge contained in Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Get a proxy filter that doesn't suck. Better yet, get rid of your proxy filter.

Comment: @Weblog: That's most likely not an option....however, a word with the admin might help.

Comment: That's bad.. My office proxy blocks any SO question with the word underSCORE in the title saying `Cricket site blocked`. Luckily I can trim the title and still view the page.

Comment: The admin says they can't help it. Just unprofessional!

Comment: So, finally changed the job and now the question is irrelevant!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem that your former company is causing for itself and needs to be addressed at the company level. Stack Exchange should not attempt to support every unreasonable web filter in existence. It would take developer time away from more useful projects, it might decrease quality for 99% of users and it would be a never-ending task because there would always be more unaddressed cases out there.

Answer (score 2):

There's not all that much anyone outside can do about incompetent administrators working for a fascist management, as any change made may well hit some other arbitrary rule. I suppose we could try to encourage them to visit [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) but the chances are low there; usually the people who miss out on such things are the people who need it most.

I suppose the one benefit is that you can tell your former coworkers to access SO from home and show off their new-found expertise.